# iScroll 4 Firefox and Internet Explorer not scrolling

Tags: iscroll

i have a problem with iScroll 4 and can't find the problem.

I have a homepage which use iScoll4. It is working on iOS7, Google Chrome and Safari. The same page is not working on Firefox 27 and IE11.

The divs:

IE11:

```
<div id="scrollChild" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transition-property: top, left; -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;">
```

Firefox:

```
<div id="scrollChild" style="top: 0px; left: 0px;">
```

Google Chrome:

```
<div id="scrollChild" style="-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.33, 0, 0.33, 1); transition: -webkit-transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.33, 0, 0.33, 1); -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);">
```

Does anyone have an idea what's the problem with FF and IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Switch to iScroll5. It's much more mature, configurable, stable, simple and comes with much better performance.

[look here](http://iscrolljs.com/)